# How do I write a query which returns a nested list using the Beam library in Haskell?

Tags: sql, postgresql, haskell, haskell-beam

I need help rewriting myQuery so that I can retrieve all the class types associated 
with a purchased class pass. The query I desire would have the signature:

```
myQuery :: Text -> Pg [(PurchasedClassPass, [ClassType])]
```

I have the following postgres schema using the Beam library:

```
import           Database.Beam
import           Database.Beam.Migrate
import           Database.Beam.Postgres
import           Data.Text                      ( Text )


data MyDb f = MyDb
  {   _class_types :: f (TableEntity ClassTypeT)
    , _class_pass_types :: f (TableEntity ClassPassTypeT)
    , _class_passes :: f (TableEntity ClassPassT)
    , _purchased_class_passes :: f (TableEntity PurchasedClassPassT)
    } deriving (Generic, Database Postgres)


data ClassTypeT f = ClassType
  { _id :: Columnar f Text
  , _name :: Columnar f Text
  }
  deriving (Generic, Beamable)

instance Table ClassTypeT where
  data PrimaryKey ClassTypeT f = ClassTypeId {
       unClassTypeId :: Columnar f Text 
    } deriving (Generic, Beamable)
  primaryKey = ClassTypeId . _id

type ClassType = ClassTypeT Identity

type ClassTypeId = PrimaryKey ClassTypeT Identity


data ClassPassT f = ClassPass
  { _class_type_id :: PrimaryKey ClassType.ClassTypeT f
  , _class_pass_type_id :: PrimaryKey ClassPassTypeT f
  , _created_at :: Columnar f LocalTime
  , _updated_at :: Columnar f LocalTime
  } deriving (Generic, Beamable)


-- the kinds of class passes which can be purchased
data ClassPassTypeT f = ClassPassType
  {   _id :: Columnar f Text
    , _name :: Columnar f Text
  }
  deriving (Generic, Beamable)

instance Table ClassPassTypeT where
    data PrimaryKey ClassPassTypeT f = ClassPassTypeId { unClassPassTypeId :: Columnar f Text } deriving (Generic, Beamable)
    primaryKey = ClassPassTypeId . _id

type ClassPassType = ClassPassTypeT Identity

type ClassPassTypeId = PrimaryKey ClassPassTypeT Identity

-- purchases
data PurchasedClassPassT f = PurchasedClassPass
  { _id :: Columnar f Text
  , _student_email :: Columnar f Text
  , _class_pass_type_id :: PrimaryKey ClassPassTypeT f
  } deriving (Generic, Beamable)

instance Table PurchasedClassPassT where
  data PrimaryKey PurchasedClassPassT f = PurchasedClassPassId { unPurchasedClassPassId :: Columnar f Text } deriving (Generic, Beamable)
  primaryKey = PurchasedClassPassId . _id

type PurchasedClassPass = PurchasedClassPassT Identity

type PurchasedClassPassId = PrimaryKey PurchasedClassPassT Identity


-- join table which expresses the many <-> many relation between 
-- class pass types and the Class types.
-- A row here linking a class pass type and the class type says that
-- the class pass can be redeemed as credit against the given class type
instance Table ClassPassT where
    data PrimaryKey ClassPassT f
      = ClassPassId
          (PrimaryKey ClassType.ClassTypeT f)
          (PrimaryKey ClassPassTypeT f)
      deriving Generic
    primaryKey =
        ClassPassId
        <$> _class_type_id
        <*> _class_pass_type_id

type ClassPass = ClassPassT Identity

instance Beamable (PrimaryKey ClassPassT)


classPassTypeClassTypeRelationship ::  
  Q Postgres
  MyDb
  s
  (ClassPassTypeT (QExpr Postgres s))
  -> Q Postgres MyDb s (ClassTypeT (QExpr Postgres s))
  -> Q Postgres
     MyDb
     s
     (ClassPassT (QExpr Postgres s), ClassPassTypeT (QExpr Postgres s),
      ClassTypeT (QExpr Postgres s))
classPassTypeClassTypeRelationship =
  manyToManyPassthrough_ (_class_passes MyDb)
    _class_pass_type_id
    _class_type_id
```

For each row in the `purchased_class_passes` table there is a foreign key in the row (`_class_pass_type_id`)
which links to the `class_pass_types table`.

This `class_pass_type` entity then has many entries in the 
`class_passes` table which then again has many `class_type` entities associated with it. 
The `class_passes` table is a join through table expressing this many to many relation between 
`class_pass_types` and `class_types`.

I need help writing a query which can return a list of all purchased class passes for a given `student_email`
and another nested list of all the class types the purchase class pass relates to
 - in other words all the class types for all the purchased class passes (filtered by `student_email`).

So this is my current failing attempt.

```
getPurchasedClassPassSummaries studentEmail = do
  purchasedClassPasses <- all_ (_purchased_class_passes MyDb)
  guard_ $ _student_email purchasedClassPasses ==. val_ studentEmail  

  classPassTypes <- related_ (MyDb ^. class_pass_types) (_class_pass_type_id purchasedClassPasses)

  classPasses <- leftJoin_ (all_ (MyDb ^. class_passes))
    (\classPass -> _class_pass_type_id classPass `references_` classPassTypes)

  classTypes <- related_ (MyDb ^. class_types) (_class_type_id classPasses)

  pure (purchasedClassPasses, classTypes)
```

Although this type checks as

```
getPurchasedClassPassSummaries :: 
  Text -> 
  Q Postgres MyDb s           
    [(
      PurchasedClassPassT (QExpr Postgres s),
      ClassTypeT (QExpr Postgres s)
    )]

myQuery :: Text -> Pg [(PurchasedClassPass, ClassType)]
myQuery studentEmail =
  runSelectReturningList $ do 
    select $ getPurchasedClassPassSummaries studentEmail
```

This is inadequate as I really would like to rewrite the query so that I can get the following 
type signature.

```
getPurchasedClassPassSummaries ::
  Text -> 
  Q Postgres MyDb s           
    [ 
      (  PurchasedClassPassT (QExpr Postgres s)
        , [ClassTypeT (QExpr Postgres s)] )
    ]
getPurchasedClassPassSummaries studentEmail = undefined

myQuery :: Text -> Pg [(PurchasedClassPass, [ClassType])]
myQuery studentEmail =
  runSelectReturningList $ do 
    select $ getPurchasedClassPassSummaries studentEmail
```